# Capybara: Find element by attribute containing something NOT

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am having the following issue in my Capybara environment:

I need to search for an element. This element contains an attribute, which is unique. The attribute is changed asynchronously. 
I need the content of this attribute, but when I just search for the attribute I am getting a nil.

I could wait until the attribute has the property, but since this is Capybaras job, I thought there might be a possible selector, which can search for something like:

```
find('button[uniqueattribute] != nil')
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attribute is being added to the button element (didn't have the attribute originally) then you can just do

```
find('button[attribute_name]')
```

which will wait (up to Capybara.max_default_wait_time seconds for a button element with that attribute to be on the page - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors.  To wait and then get the contents/value of that attribute you could do

```
find('button[attribute_name]')['attribute_name']
```

If you just want to wait until the attribute is either not there or not blank then you can do

```
find('button:not([attribute_name=""])')
```

If you need to ensure the attribute is there, but isn't blank it would be

```
find('button[attribute_name]:not([attribute_name=""])')
```

Comment: Its looking good, but unfortunately in my case the attribute already seems to be attached to the element when its loaded, but empty. Then asynchronously, it is updated with a content I don't know, therefore I cannot search for the content except for it should not be empty

Comment: @MJohnyJ Updated with how to do it via CSS if the attribute is already there but blank.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution:
You can check the length of an element by Xpath (which is awesome) with string-length.
So in my case the solution was:

```
find(:xpath, ".//button[@unique_attribute_name[string-length() != 0]]")
```

Now Capybara waits until the attribute has a value. If there are more pretty solutions, just tell me.

Comment: The XPath you show isn't valid XPath (attribute names are preceded by @ in XPath- so not really sure how that works for you.  Also, when using XPath in Capybara you should always start your XPath with .// rather than // - otherwise you defeat all scoping -  https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap.  So './/button[string-length(@unique_attribute_name) != 0]`  would be a better and legal XPath

Comment: I didn't copy and paste, shame on me and thanks on you. 
I corrected my answer.
Thanks for the hint with the xpath trap!